# Undefined method for NilClass in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Undefined method `title` for nil:NilClass

```
<% if @job.title.blank?  %>
  <h2 class="tk-ff-netto-web">
    <%= @job.title %>
  </h2>
<% else %>
  <h1> Hello </h1>
<% end  %>
```

Comment: your @job is Nil. you should check if you passed the variable from your controller properly. could you post corresponding controller?

Comment: No isn't work for me.